MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=efConstruction out of range: [1, 2147483647])>
I have the following error: MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=efConstruction out of range: [1, 2147483647])>
while I am creating HNSW indexing on milvus db. any suggestion would be great. nothing on the internet.
My vector size is 30552. maybe that can be the problem. I am not sure. just looking for a logical explanation.
UPDATE-1: I have updated my create index parameters for efconstruction parameter. here is the configuration:
{'metric_type': 'ss', 'index_type': 'bb', 'params': {'nlist': 5, 'efConstruction': 40}}
after that I am getting the following error:
MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=M out of range: [1, 2048])>

what llm are you using here that has 30552 as its embedding dimension? Thx

Actually I do not have any LLM here. just using vectorDB. that number is the output of embedding model. @Madhavan

aha, gotcha - curious, what embedding model is that? thanks!

@Madhavan it is called SpladeEmbedding which is sparse embedding type of model. you can find example code in milvus website. but be aware of the difference between dense and sparse embedding. this is a sparse embedding model.

After adding efconstruction and M parameters to my creat_index code. Problem is solved for me.
here is the my latest index parameter:
{'metric_type': 'IP', 'index_type': 'HNSW', 'params': {'nlist': 1024, 'efConstruction': 40, 'M': 1024}}
Note: you may not need nlist parameter. just ignore that one.


'nlist' is a hyperparameter of IVF_flat index.
'M', 'efConstruction', 'ef' are hyperparameters for HNSW index.

HNSW best practice params. Start with M: 4~64, larger M for larger data and larger embedding lengths. Then ef = efConstruction = M * 2.
References:

Milvus docs:  https://milvus.io/docs/index.md
HNSW docs: https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib/blob/master/ALGO_PARAMS.md


delete existing vector DB. Start a fresh.
mostly the previous indexes created cause a conflict
